# Как правильно выбрать не занятый порт для подключения?

Tags: c#, ftp, tcp

FTP: в активном режиме клиент сам должен выбрать, к какому его порту сервер должен подключиться.

Т.е. нужен какой-то свободный порт. Предполагаю следующую логику:

1. получаем рандомный номер порта в диапазоне 49152 — 65535
2. проверяем свободен ли он
3. отправляем команду PORT
4. создаем TcpListener и слушаем его

как-то так:

```
    protected void sendPORT(Socket socket)
    {
        // выбираем порт
        int iMin = 49152;
        int iMax = 65535;
        Random r = new Random();
        int port;
        do { port = iMin + r.Next(iMax - iMin); }
        while (checkPort(port));

        // делим на старший и младший байты
        int iPort1 = 0;
        int iPort2 = port;
        if (iPort2 > 255)
        {
            iPort1 = (int)(iPort2 / 256) * 256;
            iPort2 -= iPort1;
        }
        // локальный IP
        IPAddress localAddress = ((IPEndPoint)this.socket.LocalEndPoint).Address;
        // отправляем на сервер
        string command = string.Format("PORT {0},{1},{2}", localAddress.ToString().Replace('.', ','), iPort1, iPort2);
        Byte[] cmdBytes = enc.GetBytes(command.ToCharArray());
        socket.Send(cmdBytes, cmdBytes.Length, 0);

        createTCPListener(port);
    }

    private bool checkPort(int port)
    {
        // проверяем свободен ли порт
        // можно добавить еще условия
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    private void createTCPListener(int port)
    {
        // здесь создаем и слушаем порт

        TcpListener server = new TcpListener(port);
        server.Start();

        Byte[] bytes = new Byte[256];
        String data = null;

        while (true)
        {
            TcpClient client = server.AcceptTcpClient();
            data = null;
            NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();
            int i;
            while ((i = stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)) != 0)
            {
                data = enc.GetString(bytes, 0, i);
                data = data.ToUpper();
                byte[] msg = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);
                stream.Write(msg, 0, msg.Length);
            }

            // Shutdown and end connection
            client.Close();
        }
    }
```

Как в c# можно узнать - свободен ли на данный момент порт?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Объедините пункты 2 и 4 вашего алгоритма: создайте TcpListener и начните слушать. Если порт занят - будет исключение.

Comment: на каком месте оно возникнет и какого типа?

Comment: @kvvk при вызове `Start()` оно возникает. Запустите 1 раз в отладчике с занятым портом - и посмотрите что вывалится.

Comment: @kvvk только не забудьте еще свойство SocketErrorCode посмотреть - а то там 1 исключение на кучу разных ситуаций.